# Calculate machine precision on gmp arbitrary precision

Tags: c, gmp, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to obtain the machine precision on [gmp](http://gmplib.org/) variables.

To that end, I adapted the code from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), to compute the precision of a gmp with a fixed precision:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    long int precision = 100;

mpf_set_default_prec(precision); // in principle redundant, but who cares

    mpf_t machEps, one, temp; // "one" is the "1" in gmp. tmp is to comparison.
    mpf_init2(machEps, precision); 
    mpf_set_ui(machEps, 1); // eps = 1
    mpf_init_set(one,machEps); // ensure "one" has the same precision as machEps
    mpf_init_set(temp,machEps); // ensure "temp" has the same precision as machEps

    do {
        mpf_div_ui(machEps,machEps,2); // eps = eps/2
        mpf_div_ui(temp,machEps,2);    // temp = eps/2
        mpf_add(temp,temp,one);        // temp += 1
    }
    while ( mpf_cmp(temp,one)); // temp == 1
    /// print the result...
    char *t = new char[400];
    mp_exp_t expprt;
    mpf_get_str(NULL, &expprt, 10, 10, machEps);

    sprintf(t, "%se%ld", mpf_get_str(NULL, &expprt, 10, mpf_get_default_prec(), machEps), expprt);

    printf( "Calculated Machine epsilon: %s\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the result is not consistent with the wikipedia's formula, neither changes with the precision I set. What am I missing? I've also tried with double and float (c standard), and the result is correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get results that are consistent with [wikipedia's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Values_for_standard_hardware_floating_point_arithmetics), and the values depend on the precision.

However, the value - and the effective precision - only change when crossing a limb-boundary<sup>(1)</sup>. For me, that means multiples of 64, so for

```
(k-1)*64 < precision <= k*64
```

the calculated machine epsilon is

```
0.5^(k*64)
```

Some results:

```
$ ./a.out 192
Calculated Machine epsilon: 15930919111324522770288803977677118055911045551926187860739e-57
$ ./a.out 193
Calculated Machine epsilon: 8636168555094444625386351862800399571116000364436281385023703470168591803162427e-77
```

For comparison:

```
Prelude> 0.5^192
1.5930919111324523e-58
Prelude> 0.5^256
8.636168555094445e-78
```

The output of the GMP programme is in the form `mantissa,'e',exponent` where the value is

```
0.mantissa * 10^exponent
```

<sup>(1)</sup> GMP represents the floating point numbers as a pair of exponent (for base 2) and mantissa (and sign). The mantissa is maintained as an array of unsigned integers, the *limbs*. For me, the limbs are 64 bits, on 32 bit systems usually 32 bits (iirc). So when the desired precision is between `(k-1)*LIMB_BITS` (exclusive) and `k*LIMB_BITS` (inclusive), the array for the mantissa contains `k` limbs, and all of them are used, thus the effective precision is `k*LIMB_BITS` bits. Therefore the epsilon only changes when the number of limbs changes.

Comment: Ok, my results are in agreement with yours. What means "However, the value - and the effective precision - only change when crossing a limb-boundary". Can you explain on the answer? apparently that was my problem, I don't know why there is this discrete steps. (or any reference to "limb-boundary") Thanks anyway, helped a lot!

Comment: Okay, will add an explanation.

Comment: You may want to look at using the [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) library. The mpfr type uses the exact number of bits of precision requested instead of rounding up by limbs.